# Infinispan data eviction

Tags: caching, infinispan

I use infinispan cache version 5.1.6.FINA. I have configured named cache:

```
<namedCache name="cacheName">
    <locking lockAcquisitionTimeout="5000" />
    <eviction maxEntries="10" strategy="NONE" />
    <expiration lifespan="-1" maxIdle="-1" />
</namedCache>
```

I use it to store some data in memory only. I use this configuration during creating cache where key is `Long` and value is `String` and hold there only 4 elements always only 4. For this purpose I have hardcoded 4 keys: 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L and sometimes just change values of those elements.

If cache holds 2 elements with key 1L and 2L and some values and I try to add other two with his values, they replays each other. So as a result cache holds just 3 element with keys 1L, 2L, 3L or 1L, 2L, 4L. I've tried to change eviction strategy but is doesn't help. Additionally I can say that it is local environment, non clustering.

Could someone to explain me this behavior?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly this might answer your question -- when you put with the same key, value is replaced. To have more values stored, you need to differentiate keys properly. If you have 1L and 2L already cached, and then you put for example 2L and 3L, you will end up with former 1L, replaced 2L and new 3L values.

Comment: Hi tsykora, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately you are a bit incorrect. My problem is that I have for example in the cache 2 elements with keys 1L and 2L and add next two with keys 3L and 4L as a result I have in my cache only 3 elements. One of new elements for some reason doesn't want to live in there.

Comment: I see, now I fully understand your problem... which is, to be honest, quite strange. I would also expect that you will be able to store more that 3 entries into the cache. Did you try to increase maxEntries number to a higher value?

Comment: I removed eviction tag and it helped. I did it because I control count of elements in this cache. But agree with you that this behavior is quite strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `maxEntries=10`, I'd expect you would have ±8 entries in the cache, not just 3. But generally, the answer is here:

- [Cache’s number of entries never reaches configured maxEntries, why is that?](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/faqs/faqs.html#_cache_s_number_of_entries_never_reaches_configured_maxentries_why_is_that)
- [Advanced Eviction Internals](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#advanced_eviction_internals) (also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20264948/267197))

Comment: Hi, Flavius. Thanks for answer. Maybe in version 6.0.x it works like in this documentation I didn't try, but it my version 5.1.6 cache behaviors quite different.